# Flask is unable to read a file that should be next to the main.py that retrieved the environment variable for the Flask Config

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn, google-app-engine-python

I've deployed a python3.7 app in GAE, standard env.
It seems that the app cannot find the flask configuration file, sitting next to the main.py I am using as the entrypoint.

Flask keeps reporting that it's unable to load the configuration file.

```
(No such file or directory): '/srv/carescor/admin/carescor-flask.cfg'
```

The code, with the gunicorn statup works fine, outside of this GAE setup.
Am I assuming something wrong about where the config file is, after deployment?

Here's the app.yaml being used.

```
service: default
runtime: python37

env_variables:
  APP_SETTINGS: carescor-flask.cfg

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT carescor.admin.wsgi:app

instance_class: F1

handlers:

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

inbound_services:
  - warmup
```

File structure being deployed:

```
<project root>
    |
    app.yaml
    requirements.txt
    /carescor/admin
       |
       /static
       /templates
       __init__.py
       carescor-flask.cfg
       main.py
       wsgi.app
```

Contents of wsgi.app:

```
from carescor.admin.main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1) move your `env_variables` statement AFTER your `entrypoint` declaration.

2) add `/srv/` to your PATH.

Comment: On the 2nd item, are you saying to add it to the shell's PATH or to a PATH definition in the `env_variables`?

Comment: Trial and error: adding /srv in either way did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. A while ago, the needed file was .gitignored because we wanted to keep it out of the source code. That decision changed, but the .gitignore entry did not.

Hence the resulting fun. 
Thanks to everyone who looked at the question.

Comment: Your question is unlikely to help others so please consider deleting it.

Comment: environment configuration should be kept out of source control, and i am looking for a solution to this problem on GAE. why did your team go with including the configuration back to source control?

Comment: yes. please note, that you can remove certain items, such as passwords, and have your code update the flask config read those from the environment.